# Plural translation on Yii2 does not work on the production server

Tags: php, yii2

I am working on a PHP Yii2 application using the advanced template.

On my local development machine, the plural form in the translation function works as expected:

[image]

When I upload the application to the production server, the application doesn't seem to recognize the plural setup:

```
Yii::t('app', '{n, plural, =0{nothing found :(} =1{one result found} other{found # results}}', ['n'=>sizeof($results)]);
```

[image]

Not sure what could be the issue here. The PHP intl extension is installed on the production server and the other Yii::t() instances (except plural) work fine.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your ICU library is out to date, based on [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#setup-environment):

> It is also recommended that you use an ICU version equal or greater than version 49.

Comment: Thank you myesam, that's most likely it. Don't know how I didn't catch it. It will be difficult to fix it since I'm hosting on a paid service provider.

Comment: I know what you mean. I have same problem when work with different date systems. Usually I've create a component that on it, i check either ICU is installed or not, if it has been installed i use it and if it's has not been installed, i code on myself. Anyway all of them get the work down ;).